# Rendering children props in pure ReactJS (functional) component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React v0.14 supports [pure functional components](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/09/10/react-v0.14-rc1.html#stateless-function-components) (i.e. same input equals same output). Props are passed in as function arguments.

```
// Using ES6 arrow functions and an implicit return:
const PureComponent = ({url}) => (
  <div>
    <a href={url}>{url}</a>
  </div>
);

// Used like this:
<PureComponent url="http://www.google.ca" />

// Renders this:
<a href="http://www.google.ca">http://www.google.ca</a>
```

**But how do you render children of the PureComponent?** In regular stateful components you access the children with [`this.props.children`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#children), but this obviously doesn't work here.

```
const PureComponent = ({url}) => (
  <div>
    <a href={url}>{children}</a> // <--- This doesn't work
  </div>
);

<PureComponent url="http://www/google.ca">Google Canada</PureComponent>

// I want to render this:
<a href="http://www.google.ca">Google Canada</a>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Should it be `{props.children}`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add `children` to the destructuring assignment of the argument "props".

`const PureComponent = ({url, children}) => (...)`

`children` is just a prop passed to the component.  In order to use it like you are using `props.url` you need to add it to that list so it can be "pulled out" of the props object.

Comment: Typically, if your answer starts with "try this" or "I think", it probably should be a comment. There is no destructuring  assignment there

Comment: The pure component takes the props object as the first argument so the {url, children, ...} is a destructuring assignment from props into those variable.  Glad it helped.

Comment: @anotherRobLynch: So you mean I could just put `props` in place of the `{url, children}` and use `props.url` and `props.children` directly? I was wondering why it needed to be in curly brackets.

Comment: @FighterJet That would work too.  If your co-workers are not used to reading much ES6 code could be the better way to do it.  I personally like the destructured look because it keeps the JSX cleaner.